# ionic change back button icon and text

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

using ionic 3.9.2

**Objective:**
back button in `navbar` using `ios-arrow-back` style and "back" with translate pipe

---

1. with `setBackButtonText()`, manage to set back button text.
   But it's tedious to do it for every page with getting reference of nav bar, set text after view init.
   Any way to set back button text in template in which can set it like `{{ 'back' | translate }}`

---

2. How to use other icon for back button?

first try: `ion-nav-back-button`, prompt `ion-nav-back-button` not known

second try:

```
<ion-buttons start>
  <button ion-button>
    <ion-icon name="ios-arrow-back"></ion-icon>
    <p>back</p>
  </button>
</ion-buttons>
```

However, it's strange that even with `start`, the button is on right end.

**Playground:**
[ionic playground](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-i3ast3?file=pages%2Fdetails%2Fdetails.component.html)

hope to see advice, thanks

Comment: I hope this will be helpful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37643450/3786343

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Works well on android and ios

```
<ion-buttons left>
    <button ion-button (click)="dismiss()">
      <span ion-text color="primary" showWhen="ios">Back</span>
    </button>
    <button ion-button (click)="dismiss()">
        <ion-icon name="arrow-round-back" showWhen="android,windows"></ion-icon>
      </button>
  </ion-buttons>
```